# How do you sketch a signal given by x(t) = A(t/T) for time period 0 to T? Does t/T simply denote that the signal covers entire duration of T?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, waveform, signal-theory, sawtooth-waveform

Does t/T simply mean that the signal has magnitude A over the entire "T" duration? Or does it mean that it covers only a fraction? How will it look?

I tried assuming A to be some magnitude example 5 and T to be 10 sec.. and then increasing t in steps of 1 sec.. so I get magnitude of 0.5 basically for the entire 10 sec duration - am I understanding this correctly - the source of my confusion is that the waveform A(t/T) has t divided by T - so is it meant to make a shift in time? (For eg u(t-2) makes the waveform shift in time instead of the magnitude of u(t). )

Basically, I am trying to integrate two orthonormal signals given by A(t/T) and B(t/T - C) to find A,B and C and I know the steps however I was wondering if they could be visualized.

[EDIT]: Just want to add the original question statement to avoid confusion of what the A might be:
`Consider the two signals 1() and 2() given by 1() =  (/) ; 2() =  (/ − ) ; 0 ≤  ≤  We are told that 1() and 2() form an orthonormal signal set. Determine the values of the nonzero constants ,  and`

Comment: `A()` is a function. `x(t)=A(t/T)` means that `x()` is the same function as `A` but "stretched" on the `t` axis by a factor `T`.

Comment: I am not 100% confident but I think here A might have some real constant value because the question I'm looking at, asks us to find the value of A, B and C. The question statement reads: `Consider the two signals 1() and 2() given by
1() =  (/) ; 2() =  (/ − ) ; 0 ≤  ≤ 
We are told that 1() and 2() form an orthonormal signal set. Determine the
values of the nonzero constants ,  and 
`

Comment: wouldn't https://math.stackexchange.com/ be more suitable for help?

Comment: It looks like there is a implied *multiplication* between `A` and `(t/T)`, but in your question it looks like `A` is a function. But still not 100% clear from the wording, please look closer into the original to figure it out or ask for clarification.

Comment: If you define A = 5 then it is not a function t nor T, so the expression is deceptive for a constant, but if you say it is the result of an expression then t and T are irrelevant if that is given as a constant instead of say 5*A(t/T) or \$e^{-\frac{t}{T}}\$

Comment: You can't normalize the function \$\phi_1(t)=A(t/T)\$, much less form an orthonormal set with another similar function. Are you sure the actual signal functions aren't \$\sin\phi_1(t)\$ and \$\sin\phi_2(t)\$, or something like that?

Comment: Even more likely would be \$x_1(t) = A\sin(t/T)\$ and \$x_2(t)=B\sin(t/T-C)\$, and maybe a typesetting error somehow dropped the "sin" parts.

Comment: Yes, the question statement there is correct as is. Although points people have made so far also make sense. I assume since its defined as a basis function `ϕ1(t)` it must already be normalized. Therefore, I could integrate the square of the signal and put it equal to 1. That gives me  `A = sqrt(3/T)` - but again, I'm not very confident of my approach.

Comment: Yes, actually that might be true and would make so much more sense. Thank you. It maybe an error in the question book. Thanks.